# Recover crop dimensions from BufferedImage

Tags: java, crop, bufferedimage

I have two BufferedImages.  One of them is obtained by calling .subImage() from the other, however, I do not know the input to the subImage() method.  Is there an efficient way of recovering the original crop dimensions.  Since I know the width and height of the crop (as that's the width and height of the smaller image), I really only need to know the crop origin.  I know I can do this by comparing every subImage of the larger image to the smaller image, but that seems terribly inefficient.  Is there a better way?

Thanks

EDIT

For my purposes, it doesn't matter if there are multiple identical subimages, I just need one of them.  At the end of the day, I need an AffineTransform that will map the origin from the big image to the subImage.  It seems unfortunate that BufferedImage is defined to have (0,0) be the origin.

Comment: what if your subimage is a black square and your whole image has a lot of similar black squares?

Comment: Then it doesn't matter.  For my application, all I care about is finding one subimage that perfectly matches the input.

Comment: So if you find the first subimage that matches your pattern, it's ok. I think this changes a little your question :-)

Comment: looks like a computer vision problem. I am no specialist on this, but I think you should add tags (and search for techniques)  related to terms such as "pattern matching" or "template matching" and, of course, computer vision. Not an easy task, I guess.

Comment: That's what I feared, I was just hopeful that I overlooked something in the specification which could make this an easier task without resorting to looking at the pixels.

Comment: I believe the solution will depend of what kind of image you're looking for. You, know, for faces, people use two cameras to extract 3d info, for car plates, people use a different technique, and so on. Maybe specialists at SO can help you better if you narrow your problem to what kind of pattern you're looking for

Comment: if you don't need to rotate or re-scale, I think it won't be that hard :-) but I don't have enough knowledge to tell you how. Probably there are some smart ways to deal with that

Comment: No, there is no rotation, just a rectangular cropping.

Comment: Take a look on this http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/template_matching.html